# LaTeX whitespace not showing up in RMarkdown PDF

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I use `rmarkdown` and `beamer` to make teaching slides. I'm trying to insert a LaTeX equation in my slide, and this equation has a few spaces in it.

```
$Scott's \space pi = \frac{\% \space obs. \space agreements - \% \space exp. \space agreements}{1 - \% \space exp. \space agreements}$
```

When i hover on it with my cursor, Rstudio previews the equation correctly, as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image]

However, when I knit the PDF, the spaces don't appear, and I get this:

[image]

Am I missing something here?

My markdown header is as follows:

```
---
title: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
author: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
institute: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
date: "XXXXXX"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    incremental: true
    theme: "Berlin"
    colortheme: "dove"
    fonttheme: "structurebold"
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
classoption: "aspectratio=169"

---
```

The `preamble.tex' file is as follows:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=black} %section slide title
\setbeamercolor{section in foot}{fg=white, bg=black} % footsections
\setbeamercolor{part title}{fg=white, bg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
 \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.33\paperwidth,ht=2.6ex,dp=1ex,left,leftskip=2ex]{section in foot} % footsection 1
    \usebeamerfont{section in foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.33\paperwidth,ht=2.6ex,dp=1ex,center]{section in foot} % footsection 2
    \usebeamerfont{section in foot} \inserttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.34\paperwidth,ht=2.6ex,dp=1ex,right,rightskip=2ex]{section in foot} % footsection 3
    \usebeamerfont{section in foot} XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%

  \vskip0pt%
}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}{
  \centering
  \begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{\paperwidth}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{part title}
    \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{column}
  \end{columns}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please don't ever use math mode for whole words, besides the missing spaces, the kerning is all messed up!

Instead you can use the `\text{...}` macro from the `amsmath` package (which is automatically loaded by beamer)

```
---
title: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
author: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
institute: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
date: "XXXXXX"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    incremental: true
    theme: "Berlin"
    colortheme: "dove"
    fonttheme: "structurebold"
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
classoption: "aspectratio=169"

---

- $\text{Scott's pi} = \frac{\text{\% obs. agreements} - \text{\% exp. agreements}}{1 - \text{\% exp. agreements}}$
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! can you pls edit your screenshot so that my email doesn't show up? i forgot to remove it before pasting the preamble.

Comment: @wrahool Done :) Your email will still show up in the revision history of your question. If you want to erase it completely, you could try to flag your question for moderator attention, they can redact information from the history

Answer (score -1):

You can add

```
\text{ }
```

inside the equations to add a space. This should work with different format. For example, if you want to add space around the symbol %, you can consider

```
\text{ \% }
```

in a mathematical equation.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use this to add space to your equations in RMarkdown: http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_119.html. In your case, you just need to replace `\space` by `\:`.

Example of a `.Rmd` file:

````
---
title: "Equation with space"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

$$Scott's \: pi = \frac{\% \: obs. \: agreements - \% \: exp. \: agreements}{1 - \% \: exp. \: agreements}$$
````

Outuput:

[image]

Comment: Please don't ever use math mode for whole words, the kerning is all messed up!